# How to generate access token in backend only with user email?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, access-token, abp, password-less

I would like to get some help from you since I've been searching all around and I can not find the solution to my question,

My use case is the next one:

I have an application developed in ABP 6 and using Angular UI, in the login I have a button that allows me to redirect to a SAML identity provider that is returning a code, I redirect the SAML application to a route in my Angular app and I read the incoming parameters to call a backend endpoint and get the email of the user that succeeded the SAML login process,

So now, I need to get this email, search if this exists in my user's table and then generate an access token for that user, as you can see I am not able to use the user password, and I need to generate the token based on the user since in the whole application I am using some claims that are included in the token that is generated with the default password flow

I've been following the tutorial recommended for the community [Implementing passwordless authentication with asp.net core](https://community.abp.io/posts/implementing-passwordless-authentication-with-asp.net-core-identity-c25l8koj), but this is specific for MVC application, I am not able to run the code `await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user,isPersistent: false);` since I am not using MVC.

I found the method `GenerateUserTokenAsync` but it returns a token as a string with 5 numbers, and as far as I understand the result of the request to `connect/token` is a JSON with the access_token, refresh_token, and some other keys

Does someone have an idea or solution for this? Thanks!